# Shiv'a Asar Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seventeen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were 117 judges sitting on the Temple Mount. Source: [*Rambam*, *Sanhedrin* chapter 1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e101n.htm): 71 in the main body, plus two smaller bodies of 23 each.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest *perek* in *Tanach* is Ps. 117.

Comment: This is just as "halachically arbitrary" as your [other answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3787/759).

Answer (score 4):

Shir HaShirim has 117 Pesukim

Answer (score 2):

Gematria from the Parsha - HoOdom HoOdom Hazeh = 117

Answer (score 2):

117 AD[E](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eorum) is the year the Kitos War ended. (This answer is not a good one, as it's using an halachically arbitrary starting point for the count of years, but I figured I'd throw it in anyway.) Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitos_War.

Comment: By any chance, did you mean ADS (anno... suorum)? Cute coinage, anyway.

Comment: @Alex, I don't know Latin, but I asked someone who does (Ryan Platte, at Washington University) how to say "in the year of their lord", and he said that it's _anno domini sui_ (which he translated as "in the year of their own lord") if the "their" refers back to the subject of the sentence, but _anno domini eorum_ if the "they" merely means "some people".

Comment: Honorable mention for the aforediscussed coinage and for the affectation "an halachically."