# Minhag of throwing Challah at the Friday night Seuda

Tags: minhag, bread, challah-shabbat-bread, leil-shabbat

[Aruch HaShulchan 167:31](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=307&hilite=) and [Be'er Hataiv 167:22](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=126) both say that it is forbidden to throw the (Challah) bread. I have heard that there are some people (I heard that there are some Rabannim who do so) that have a Minhag to throw the bread when passing it around Friday night. Is there a source for this Minhag? What is the reason? How does it circumvent the problem of throwing bread?

Comment: My grandfather and father in law, both sefardim (persia and lebanon) throw the bread, both shabbos night and day. Both have told me that it is forbidden to pass bread from hand to hand (with vague mention of a relation to customs for the deceased) no halachic source, just minhag avoseihem

Comment: @nikmasi http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16063

Comment: My father does not pass from hand to hand either, however neither does he throw it. He places it down on the table, and the one next to it takes it and passes it on in the same manner.

Comment: my own theory is that in certain countries they did not eat together at a single table but each person had their own small table (I believe this was true in the times of the gemarah) so passing a plate or whatever wasn't really feasible

Answer (score 3):

I was told orally that the Noda Bihudah, if I recall correctly, defends those who have such a practice as we seek to make our tables similar to the Mizbeach, and the meat that was to be placed on the fire on the Mizbeach (altar) in the Temple was thrown (past a gap between the ramp and Mizbeach).

Comment: Can you source this answer?

Comment: Shalom, if there was a gap between the ramp and the altar (which I don't recall ever hearing before), that surely wasn't the reason for throwing: after all, _kohanim_ regularly stepped over it (for _nisuch hayayin_ for example per _maseches Tamid_).

Comment: Isn't throwing *bread* more stringent than throwing other types of food like meat?

Comment: My rov, R' Shimshon Yeshaya Adler Shlit"a (Monsey, NY) throws because of the throwing upon the altar, but I have not heard of a gap.

Comment: So the source for throwing a korban is in Zevachim 104.       רבי אליעזר אומר דם אע"פ שאין בשר שנאמר (דברים יב, כז) ודם זבחיך ישפך א"כ מה ת"ל ועשית עולותיך הבשר והדם לומר לך מה דם בזריקה אף בשר בזריקה הא למדת שריוח יש בין כבש למזבח

Answer (score 0):

A rabbi just explained that we throw challah at simchas to differentiate placing it in one's hand at funerals. We don't want to bring bad luck.

Comment: That may be why we do not put it into a hand. But why throw, and not put on the table?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Consider registering your account to utilize more features of the site.

Answer (score 0):

i have been told that the actual custom is to not pass it by hand but rather to place on the table or a tray for the others to take, and not necessarily to throw it. the reason being that the challah is zecher for the "mon" that was given directly by Hashem and therefore it (the challah) should not be taken from a person directly.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16063/759